# Ember choking upon encountering large data sets

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Looking for a solution to an issue caused by large data sets forcing Ember to lock up the browser while it tries to process the data.

For pagination, I'm using tchak's handy [pagination mixin](https://gist.github.com/1559628) to paginate approximately  13,000+ objects being loaded from a backend API.

The Ember Data objects contain an ID, one text attribute and several number attributes.

The problem is it takes close to a minute before the browser finishes processing the data, rendering the browser unusable in the meantime. Firefox even goes as far as to issue a warning that a script is using up all browser resources and suggests that script be terminated.

I've written my own pagination mixin that requests objects by range, i.e. items 10-25, and it works generally well except for one serious limitation: sorting. To sort the data, I need to make additional requests to the backend and reload the objects even if some of them have already been loaded.

I would love to be able to load all of the content upfront to simplify the process of sorting without doing additional requests to the backend API. I'm looking for guidance on how to tackle this issue but I'm open to an entirely alternative approach.

If nothing else, is it possible to reduce the resource footprint Ember places on the browser as it tries to load all 13k objects into the ArrayController?

---

I'm using Ember 1.0.0-pre2 with the latest Ember Data (currently at Revision 10).

On the backend is Rails 3.2.8.

---

**Update** I sidestepped the issue by loading data into an ArrayController property other than `content`. This brought the load times down from over a minute to only a few seconds. I then slice the requested number of items and load those into content. This works well for any number of items, at the cost of not being able to easily sort the data.

Comment: Could you please share some code regarding the solution? 
I am facing the same problem and it would be a great help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at **[Ember Table](http://addepar.github.com/ember-table/)**. The demo shows a table with 500 000 records and works very fast. Digging around the source code might help.

Comment: +1 for this. The problem is most likely that you're trying to render them all at once.

Comment: I only rendered 15-20 items, but if you see my update above the issue seems to be related to how ArrayController handles content.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you query a view from your db that handles the sorting? Pass in the sort conditions in the query string ?sortBy=name&sortAsc=true

Comment: And I just answered my own question regarding GET a range of data. Say for a single month or a fiscal quarter